# Cisco visual message waiting indicator (VMWI or MVI) without SIP

Tags: telephony, cisco, cisco-axl, cisco-jtapi

How can I programmatically illuminate Cisco IP Phones Visual message waiting indicator (VMWI or MWI)?

*P.S.: I have a similar question [Cisco visual message waiting indicator ( VMWI or MVI )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260123/cisco-visual-message-waiting-indicator-vmwi-or-mvi) but this is different since I do not look for SIP message solution since it requires extra firmware installation.*